# Toggle SideBar Menu from other component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

How can i implement sidebar toggle menu in my angular app. I'm confused on how to call the sidebar menu in the other component. My toggle button is found on the header component. It's purpose is show the sidebar menu when i click the toggle button on the header component.

> header.component.html

```
  <div class="navbar-header"><a id="toggle-btn" href="#" class="menu-btn"><i class="icon-bars"> </i></a><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
              <div class="brand-text"><span>MCDONALDS</span></div></a></div>
```

> sidebar.component.html

```
<nav class="side">
  <h1>CLICK TO Show Me</h1>
  </nav>
```

> core.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
```

[image]

Comment: Do the two components have a common parent component?

Comment: @Vega. Yes. they are under the core.component.html. Pls see updated image

Comment: The both have core component as parent? The structure doesn't tell about it

Comment: Yes. Did you see the image?

Comment: Yes the image doesn't tell how they are related. Post core.html please

Comment: @Vega. Please check again. I've added it

Answer (score 6):

You can use shared service to open sidebar. Create a service vith `EventEmitter` and emit an event when you want to open a sidebar. Then, in sidebar component, subscribe to that `EventEmitter` and open/close sidebar every time when event is fired.

For example:

Service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CoreService {
  public toggleSidebar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Header

```
public openSidebar() {
  this.coreService.toggleSidebar.emit();
}
```

Sidebar

```
this.coreService.toggleSidebar.subscribe(() => {
  //open your sidebar by setting classes, whatever
});
```

Comment: @IIyaSurmay. Can you do it using my code above. Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided the code of your class, just html. Paste it here.

Comment: I didn't put anything in typescript yet

Comment: In sidebar, where this subscribe code should I put ?